# points in affine toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

I am reading Toric Variety from Cox, little and In proposition 1.3.1, I saw this proposition about which I have one question[image]
As you can see, they have written that the map $\gamma: S \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, induces a surjective $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}[S] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. I cant figure out what will be the induced map,It will be great if you an give me some idea how the induced map will look like?

Comment: You've written "injective" but the book writes "surjective". Perhaps that is part of your confusion?

Comment: Sorry I meant surjective

Comment: Happily enough, you can fix that with an [edit].

Comment: So, can you help me!